# Import composite/ntsc-signal

Tags: video, camera, composite-video, signal

I already googled a lot and mostly read that importing composite Signal to the Raspberry is *almost* impossible. I would just take a webcam and proceed since it seems to be a lot easier.

The problem is, I already have [this camera](https://learn.adafruit.com/ttl-serial-camera/wiring-the-camera) and just wanted to know if there is absolutely no way to get that NTSC-signal on the Raspberry (perhaps by connecting it directly to some pins?).

If not, I will just get a webcam as I said, but I wanted to check that before I can admit that  the investment in the TTL Camera was useless.

Comment: You can use the TTL option by connecting it to the UART of the Pi to download image still. But as Craig mentioned only a capture card will give you a composite video signal.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to directly connect the composite signal directly to the Raspberry Pi.  The only option would be to use a USB capture card with composite input. But unless you want general composite input, for instance if you want a specialized camera, I would just get a supported USB camera or, depending on your needs, the [Raspberry Pi Camera Module](http://www.raspberrypi.org/product/camera-module/).

On a more general note, there is no analog input on the Raspberry Pi so any analog signal input (including audio) requires additional hardware.