# RCA (NTSC) Camera input, is becoming an absolute nightmare!

Tags: camera

A couple of my engineer coworkers and I have been spending many days trying to get simple RCA camera input to work on a raspi, but nothing works and we are so frustrated at this point that I think the whole project is going to be scrapped.

I have tried a few USB-to-RCA converts and some purely USB webcams but always get errors or weird images. This occurs on various Pi's and OS's. But never any issue for Windows..

We need a more direct/reliable approach and I was wondering if I can somehow solder an RCA jack to the Picamera input port for direct signal input without all the funky converters, or any similar hacks?

I know raspberry pi has a whole assortment of cameras I can pick from but none will work for us, and I require using a specific camera that is NTSC.

Is it possible to hotwire an RCA input (soldering directly to PCB pads/traces)? Or an RCA-to-ribbon cable adapter, Or any USB-to-RCA converts that are guaranteed to just work??

I need a solution soon as I don't think management can justify us continuing without producing any results.

Comment: Never Twice Same Colour?

Comment: @TomasBy that'd be `color` for a'merkin system

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  What is the overall task?

Comment: Read frames from our camera into a raspberry pi (for OpenCV processing).

Comment: @TomasBy when it is working at all then the color is always greenish, with lots of stripes/lines in the image.

Comment: Well, I was half joking. Did you see [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19811/import-composite-ntsc-signal).

Comment: you require a specific camera, that has an RCA jack, but you also tried different webcams? Why?
And did the setup of SpecificCam->RCA2USB also work on Windows (7?8?10?), or did it also produce greenish image and stripes (because those do not sound like incompatibility symptoms on the Pi, but rather like a bad cam/bad frame grabber...)?

Comment: One of the engineers I am working with was able to solve our issue using DKMS and supplemented kernel drivers.. Our usb converts are now working just fine.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make an RPi accept the RCA video signal directly.

You could try RCA->USB converters based on [Stk1160](https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Stk1160_based_USB_2.0_video_and_audio_capture_devices) chipset. There's even a [blog](http://easycap.blogspot.com/) dedicated to this chipset and Linux.

If you get a converter and it doesn't work, try to revert to an old Raspbian release (2013) to get the old easycap driver. Newer drivers dropped support of some of the STK clones.